# Hahn Banach Theorem application on $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $L$ be the linear subspace of $C[0,1]$ given by $L = \{x(t) \in C[0,1] : x(t) = \text{constant}\}$

Let $f_0\in L^*$, $f_0(x)= x(0)$ and $L_1=\text{span}(L,t)$ . Find a functional $f\in L_1^*$ such that $f|_c=f_0$ and $||f||=||f_0||$

Please provide me some hints/answer

Comment: I don't understand, there's an "if" after "and" (second row) which does not make much sense.

Comment: @qwertyguy I have edited the question. Please provide me some hint

Comment: Hint: You don't really need to do all that much to $f_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $f|_c$ means $f|_L$. Furthermore I suppose that $C[0,1]$ is eqipped with the usual $|| \cdot||_{\infty} - $ norm.

We have: $x \in L_1 \iff $ there are $x_1 \in L$ and $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $x(t)=x_1(t)+at.$

Now define $f\in L_1^*$ by $f(x):=x(0).$

For $x \in L$ we have $a=0,$ hence $x=x_1$ and therefore $f(x)=f_0(x).$

This shows that $$f|_L=f_0.$$

It is your turn to show that  $||f_0||=1=||f||.$